# How to extract vectors from a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, vector-graphics

I have a PDF file with vector images inside it. (I downloaded it from the internet, so I do not have any originals.)

I wish to extract the vectors so that I can overlay them on some other images; use them in print media, or on a website.

How do I extract the specific vectors from the PDF file?

Is there, perhaps, any software which can extract the vectors from a PDF file? (Preferably free.)

Comment: @slhck: I meant [Vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics). I did use Inkscape, and It works as expected. Can you please put your comment as an Answer, so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), which is a free, open source and cross-platform vector graphics application. It will allow you to import the PDF files and select embedded vectors:

[image]

<sub>Image from [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/inkscape/9781849517201/ch03s13.html).</sub>

You can then edit the vectors and process as you like.

[General documentation](https://inkscape.org/en/learn/) is available on the Inkscape website. Details about PDF importing can be found here:

- [PDF in Importing other File Formats](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import-other-formats.html?highlight=PDF) — Inkscape Beginners' Guide 1.0 documentation
- [Time for action — importing a PDF into Inkscape](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/inkscape/9781849517201/ch03s13.html) – O'Reilly's book Inkscape by Bethany Hiitola, chapter 3

Note that on Linux it like requires X11. There is also a native Windows version.

Alternatively, you may want to give Adobe Illustrator a go (paid software).

Comment: On Linux it like requires X11 - there is also a native Windows version (which I just used nicely for extracting a vector drawing from a PDF).

Comment: Works, only the "Detailed documentation" link is not pointing to details on _importing PDF_ but showing an overview for learning resources titled "Learning Inkscape". IMO a link to the specific docs would be more "Detailed": Find
[PDF in Importing other File Formats — Inkscape Beginners' Guide 1.0 documentation](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import-other-formats.html?highlight=PDF) or O'Reilly's book _Inkscape_
by Bethany Hiitola, chapter 3
  [Time for action — importing a PDF into Inkscape](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/inkscape/9781849517201/ch03s13.html).

Comment: @hc_dev Sure, added. Next time, feel free to propose edits to existing answers to improve them.

Answer (score 34):

While Inkscape is an awesome way to do it, for those lacking X11, you can also extract individual pages of a PDF into SVG format using the **poppler-utils** at the command line. For example, to extract just page 30:

```
$ pdftocairo -f 30 -l 30 -svg  somehugemanual.pdf  myextractedpage.svg
```

You can then use your favorite vector editor (mine is Inkscape) to isolate the image from the text.

Alternately, if you're a hardcore command-line user, you can extract to EPS (encapsulated postscript) and use `sed` to hide all the text (which happens to be between BT and ET lines for pdftocairo). Here's how:

```
$ pdftocairo -f 30 -l 30 -eps  manual.pdf  - | sed '/^BT$/,/^ET$/ d' > myimage.eps
```

And, if you're really insane to avoid using X11, you can even shrink the bounding box of the image from the command line using Ghostscript's `eps2eps` command:

```
$ eps2eps myimage.eps myimage-bb.eps
```

I've tested this and it works great. However, personally, I find it easier to just use Inkscape.

Comment: +1 your command line strips all text.. but do you know how to also strip all images? I'am looking for a solution where only the vector graphic is left :)

Comment: Does this work for you? `cat foo.eps | sed '/^8 dict dup begin$/,/^Q$/ c Q' > nobitmaps.eps`

Comment: but is it then possible to check if the eps file even has vector graphic? :)

Comment: I suppose you could use Ghostscript's eps2eps to distill it down to its smallest bounding box and see if it's completely empty. But this is beginning to become a new question. Feel free to ask and I'm sure if I don't answer, someone will.

Comment: thanks for your help so far :) have created a question if you have time to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383387/how-to-get-bounding-boxes-of-elements-in-eps-files

Comment: On arch linux (and possibly other distros) `epstoeps` is named `eps2eps`

Comment: The command that converts in eps doesn't work for me. Seems like the eps file is invalid

Comment: @raffamaiden: I've updated the answer so the `sed` step is more robust. Try again. If it doesn't work, post a link to the PDF file.

Comment: @hackerb9 thanks, now the eps is readable, but the image is in really low density and some text still remains around it. The pdf is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02413.pdf), and the image is at page 7

Comment: Seems to be a misfeature in `pdftocairo`: it is rasterizing the image to 150dpi when converting to `eps`. You can change the resolution using `-r 300`. It doesn't have this problem when creating `svg`, so I'm looking into a workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure why that PDF is troublesome, but I've written a little shell script, [extractsurface.sh](https://gist.github.com/hackerb9/5d89b44e35469714ed5eb7a3d852c97c) to handle such files. It uses `xml_grep` to extract the image as SVG. Your image from page 7 is [here](https://gist.github.com/hackerb9/5d89b44e35469714ed5eb7a3d852c97c#file-example-svg).

Comment: Clever use of poppler/pdf2cairo to extract SVG. The additional cleaning from text is a nice bonus (although not asked). I hope to improve it with headings, command explanation and links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/) (paid, not a subscription, you have to pay for every major version), which is available for Windows and Mac.