# Strip text and images from eps

Tags: pdf, eps

I need to strip both text and images from an EPS file generated from a PDF file.. I only want to leave the vector graphic

I found a way to strip all text

```
$ pdftocairo -eps test.pdf - | sed '/BT/,/ET/ d' > myimage.eps
```

Now I just need to strip all images

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment on [How to extract vectors from a PDF file?](https://superuser.com/questions/302045/how-to-extract-vectors-from-a-pdf-file/884445?noredirect=1#comment1936384_884445), you can do it from the command line like so:

```
pdftocairo -eps  diagram.pdf  - | 
    sed '/BT/,/ET/ d; /^8 dict dup begin$/,/^Q$/ c Q' > vector.eps
```

If you need to extract page 30 (for example) of a document, use `pdfcairo -f 30 -l 30 ...`.

Comment: NOTE: This is not a general solution for EPS. This works only with `pdftocairo`.